# Mentioned On A Blog By A "Hacker" - Should I Care?

Tags: privacy, attack-prevention, google, black-hat

Some (insert noun here) who seems to be a black hat hacker thinks that I am his #1 enemy and has posted some of my information on his blog. He is mad because I am advertising for others. The information he posted on his blog can be found using Google. He has also sent me some tweets calling me every name in the book. By reading his blog and Twitter, he sounds like he has some anger issues so I'm probably not the only person who he has targeted. He didn't post any personal information (name, address, phone number, etc) which I'm glad. I'm wondering if I should be worried about this? Is there anything I can really do? If this continues, is there anything I can really do (considering he's in a different country)? Is there anything I can/should be prepared for him to do to me?

Comment: I know its the hardest thing in the world, but trust me... You gotta just ignore the guy. These types of [plural nouns] feed off of any kind of response. Its a good thing he didnt post personal info. Push him, though, and that might not be the case much longer.

Comment: Few real hackers do social media - the exception being "hacktivists," who want to draw as much attention to their activities as possible. Usually, exploits will be posted with relative anonymity. No black-hat hackers go online telling everyone that they're black-hat hackers - they're too smart.

Comment: @KnightOfNi A lot of "real" hackers use Twitter, though. halvar, comex, kernelbof, spender, etc. It's actually one of the best resources for finding out fun news.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So there is nothing you can do about his activity, except to ignore it as the comments suggest.

What you *can* do, is to re-evaluate your security practices, and make sure your house is in order in case he decides he wants to try to do some digital damage, to ensure you're as well protected as can be.

This means:

1. Choose strong passwords.
2. Don't reuse passwords.
3. Turn on two-factor auth anywhere that offers it.
4. Watch your bank accounts and credit history for anomalies.  No need to be paranoid, just keep an eye on it.
5. Don't associate email accounts with other online accounts unless your email account offers two factor authentication.
6. Clean up after yourself.  Don't leave junk hanging around in the ether for someone to find and possibly use against you.  Delete old email you don't need.  Don't create accounts on websites you won't ever use again.  Delete shared files that are past their prime.
7. Be careful about clicking links in emails.  Don't if you can avoid it, and watch for other forms of phishing and malware delivery.
8. Don't install/enable crap you don't need (Java in the browser) and keep the things you *do* need updated. (Flash, Acrobat Reader, etc.)

I'm sure there are other things you can do that aren't coming to me off the top of my head, but this is a good start to ensuring that anyone who wishes you harm will have the bar raised on progressing beyond Internet taunts.